# Access VBA Form current record is deleted

Tags: ms-access

I'm using Access 2003.

I have a form (`FormA`) that displays the fields of a row in `TableA`. On the form I have a button that opens a dialog with a listbox that lists all of the rows of `TableA`. A delete button on the dialog form allows the user to delete a selected row from the `TableA`, The user then closes the window and is returned to `FormA`.
If the user deleted the currently viewed row, the fields on the form show `#DELETED`.
I coded a `Me.Form.Requery` upon returning from the dialog. When it executes I get a runtime error that the record is deleted. Instead of the error, I expected the form to requery and reposition the current record.
I have code in `Sub Form_Current()`. Just to see if that was affecting the requery process I commented it out. Now the form is requeried as expected.

It seems that existence of `Form_Current()` prevents the requery. I tried coding a `Me.Requery` in `Form_Current` and all I did was loop.
The code I have in `Form_Current()` requeues subforms. So it's a requirement that the form gets requeued before requesting a requeue of the subforms.

Is there a way to requeue the before `Form_Current()` gets called? Is there a better approach?
Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to put the requery in the dialog:

```
Forms!FormA.Requery
```